# Creating hostsname aliases through dscl does not work in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, hosts-file, hostname

I read a few places that dscl is preferred over /etc/hosts for adding hostnames (for instance when developing). But in Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8) I cannot get it to work ([others too](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4185006?start=0&tstart=0)). I have read others that report other changes in 10.8 that affect dscl too. Anything I can do to make it work?

```
$ sudo dscl localhost -create /Local/Default/Hosts/test1 IPAddress 127.0.0.1
$ ping test1
ping: cannot resolve test1: Unknown host
# OK, that did not work
$ sudo dscl localhost -readall /Local/Default/Hosts IPAddress
IPAddress: 127.0.0.1
RecordName: test1
$ sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
$ ping test1
ping: cannot resolve test1: Unknown host
```

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 3):

Local OpenDirectory Hosts are no longer working on Mountain Lion (and possibly Lion). 
My guess is that this stopped working when they moved from DirectoryService to opendirectoryd.

Hopefully /etc/hosts can still be used in your environment.

Comment: Cool. Any background info (like a link to this)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is intentional. Perhaps you should create a bug report for this.